# Suggesting Reviewers: How to find institutional affiliations

Tags: journals, peer-review

Many journals recommend that authors suggest potential reviewers. They also often require the institutional affiliation to be listed. However, many researchers who have published in relevant, high-level journals do not necessarily have this information public and some are not affiliated with an institution at all.

How should I proceed in these situations?

Comment: If they don't have active websites, do you really want them as reviewers? Hint: Reviewers should be easily reachable :)

Comment: Show me a university that does not publicly list its faculty.  I claim no such institution exists.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson they certainly do exist, although they tend to be quite obscure. For example, An Hui Normal University - I grant I didn't search thoroughly, but when I poked around the website just now I didn't find any list of faculty.

Comment: @scaaahu but can you find a list of faculty?

Comment: @Allure In Chinese, yes, e.g. faculty of Physics and Electronic Information http://physics.ahnu.edu.cn/5536/view . In English, I am afraid not.

Comment: @Allure On their English web page http://www2.ahnu.edu.cn/english/ , they provide contact us button http://www.ahnu.edu.cn/3217/view which gives out their webmaster email address, you can use that address to ask a particular faculty member's address. This is the only way for non-Chinese speaking people to find out how to contact them, I think. My point is that you can find them if you want to.

Comment: @scaaahu very impressive. Curious: how'd you get there from their English webpage? Which links did you click?

Comment: @Allure Actually, I think using [Baidu](https://www.baidu.com/) is much easier than using Google when searching for info in China. You go to Baidu, enter Anhui normal university, you'll find a lot info about that school in English and Chinese. Google tried very hard to get into China, never succeeded. I think this is part of what Trump is trying to do.

Comment: @Allure I used Baidu and found a web page https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Anhui_Normal_University/members which has 375 members. I don't know if it has the thing you look for.

Comment: @scaaahu great, I will try that next time instead of trying to click around the institution's website.

Answer (score 3):

How do you know of these potential reviewers in the first place?

If you know them personally, then you probably also know which institution they're in. If you don't know them personally but have read their papers which are intimately related to yours, then you can look at the first page of their papers to see their affiliation. If you read of them from books, you can still look at the title pages which should list their affiliation.

If they don't have affiliations, then simply write "unaffiliated".